# Does iOS 16 break SVG icons in Ionic/Cordova mobile apps?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, svg

I have a very old mobile app for iOS made in Ionic 3 with Cordova 5.

Before iOS 16 everything works well, but now I have a very strange behaviour for SVG icons.

**Browsing the app's pages, the SVG icons sometimes are not completely rendered.**

This image shows it very well:

[image]

I have tried to use a very simple SVG instead of my original SVGs and it works fine, so I think it's a bug introduced in iOS 16 for (particular) SVG 1.1 that I use.

Here is the **source for a SVG icon** that gives me the problem:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 22.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Livello_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 215.4 112.7" style="enable-background:new 0 0 215.4 112.7;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#2F2F30;}
    .st1{display:none;fill:none;stroke:#1C1CF4;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
<path class="st0" d="M52.3,98.6c-2.3,0-4.3,1.9-4.3,4.3s1.9,4.3,4.3,4.3c2.3,0,4.3-1.9,4.3-4.3S54.7,98.6,52.3,98.6z"/>
<circle class="st0" cx="11.7" cy="102.8" r="4.3"/>
<circle class="st0" cx="21.9" cy="102.8" r="4.3"/>
<circle class="st0" cx="32" cy="102.8" r="4.3"/>
<circle class="st0" cx="42.2" cy="102.8" r="4.3"/>
<path class="st0" d="M62.5,98.6c-2.3,0-4.3,1.9-4.3,4.3s1.9,4.3,4.3,4.3c2.3,0,4.3-1.9,4.3-4.3S64.8,98.6,62.5,98.6z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M54.2,90.9c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.1,0.9,0.1c1.9,0,3.7-1.3,4.2-3.3c0.3-1.1,0.1-2.2-0.6-3.2c-0.6-1-1.6-1.6-2.7-1.9
    c-2.3-0.5-4.6,0.9-5.1,3.2c-0.3,1.1-0.1,2.2,0.6,3.2C52.1,90,53,90.7,54.2,90.9z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M14.6,82c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.1,0.9,0.1c0.8,0,1.6-0.2,2.3-0.7c1-0.6,1.6-1.6,1.9-2.7c0.3-1.1,0.1-2.2-0.6-3.2
    c-0.6-1-1.6-1.6-2.7-1.9c-2.3-0.5-4.6,0.9-5.1,3.2c-0.3,1.1-0.1,2.2,0.6,3.2S13.4,81.8,14.6,82z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M29.5,81c0.3-1.1,0.1-2.2-0.6-3.2c-0.6-1-1.6-1.6-2.7-1.9c-2.3-0.5-4.6,0.9-5.1,3.2c-0.5,2.3,0.9,4.6,3.2,5.1
    c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.1,0.9,0.1c0.8,0,1.6-0.2,2.3-0.7C28.6,83.1,29.3,82.1,29.5,81z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M36.2,78.2c-2.3-0.5-4.6,0.9-5.1,3.2c-0.2,1.1-0.1,2.2,0.6,3.2c0.6,1,1.6,1.6,2.7,1.9c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.1,0.9,0.1
    c1.9,0,3.7-1.3,4.2-3.3C40,81,38.5,78.7,36.2,78.2L36.2,78.2z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M46.1,80.4c-1.1-0.3-2.2-0.1-3.2,0.6c-1,0.6-1.6,1.6-1.9,2.7c-0.2,1.1-0.1,2.2,0.6,3.2c0.6,1,1.6,1.6,2.7,1.9
    c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.1,0.9,0.1c1.9,0,3.7-1.3,4.2-3.3C49.9,83.2,48.4,80.9,46.1,80.4z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M65.9,84.9c-2.3-0.5-4.6,0.9-5.1,3.2c-0.5,2.3,0.9,4.6,3.2,5.1c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.1,0.9,0.1c0.8,0,1.6-0.2,2.3-0.7
    c1-0.6,1.6-1.6,1.9-2.7c0.3-1.1,0.1-2.2-0.6-3.2C68,85.8,67,85.1,65.9,84.9z"/>
<circle class="st0" cx="107.5" cy="48.4" r="4.3"/>
<circle class="st0" cx="107.5" cy="7.8" r="4.3"/>
<circle class="st0" cx="107.5" cy="18" r="4.3"/>
<circle class="st0" cx="107.5" cy="28.1" r="4.3"/>
<circle class="st0" cx="107.5" cy="38.3" r="4.3"/>
<circle class="st0" cx="107.5" cy="58.6" r="4.3"/>
<path class="st0" d="M60.5,75.3c0.7,0.5,1.5,0.7,2.3,0.7c1.4,0,2.8-0.7,3.6-2c0.6-1,0.8-2.1,0.6-3.2s-0.9-2.1-1.9-2.7
    c-1-0.6-2.1-0.8-3.2-0.6c-1.1,0.2-2.1,0.9-2.7,1.9s-0.8,2.1-0.6,3.2S59.5,74.7,60.5,75.3z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M26.3,53.4c0.7,0.5,1.5,0.7,2.3,0.7c1.4,0,2.8-0.7,3.6-2c0.6-1,0.8-2.1,0.6-3.2c-0.2-1.1-0.9-2.1-1.9-2.7
    c-1-0.6-2.1-0.8-3.2-0.6c-1.1,0.2-2.1,0.9-2.7,1.9c-0.6,1-0.8,2.1-0.6,3.2C24.7,51.9,25.3,52.8,26.3,53.4z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M34.8,58.9c0.7,0.5,1.5,0.7,2.3,0.7c1.4,0,2.8-0.7,3.6-2c0.6-1,0.8-2.1,0.6-3.2c-0.2-1.1-0.9-2.1-1.9-2.7
    c-2-1.3-4.6-0.7-5.9,1.3c-0.6,1-0.8,2.1-0.6,3.2C33.2,57.3,33.9,58.3,34.8,58.9z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M43.4,64.3c0.7,0.4,1.5,0.7,2.3,0.7c0.3,0,0.6,0,0.9-0.1c1.1-0.2,2.1-0.9,2.7-1.9s0.8-2.1,0.6-3.2
    s-0.9-2.1-1.9-2.7c-2-1.3-4.6-0.7-5.9,1.3c-0.6,1-0.8,2.1-0.6,3.2S42.4,63.7,43.4,64.3z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M51.9,69.8c0.7,0.4,1.5,0.7,2.3,0.7c0.3,0,0.6,0,0.9-0.1c1.1-0.2,2.1-0.9,2.7-1.9c1.3-2,0.7-4.6-1.3-5.9
    c-2-1.3-4.6-0.7-5.9,1.3C49.4,65.9,50,68.5,51.9,69.8z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M73.6,73.6c-2-1.3-4.6-0.7-5.9,1.3c-0.6,1-0.8,2.1-0.6,3.2s0.9,2.1,1.9,2.7c0.7,0.4,1.5,0.7,2.3,0.7
    c0.3,0,0.6,0,0.9-0.1c1.1-0.2,2.1-0.9,2.7-1.9C76.2,77.5,75.6,74.8,73.6,73.6z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M79.4,56.3L79.4,56.3c-0.7-0.9-1.7-1.5-2.8-1.6c-1.1-0.1-2.2,0.2-3.1,0.8c-1.9,1.4-2.2,4.1-0.8,6
    c0.8,1.1,2.1,1.7,3.4,1.7c0.9,0,1.8-0.3,2.6-0.9C80.5,60.8,80.8,58.1,79.4,56.3z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M51.3,30.9c0.9,0,1.8-0.3,2.6-0.9c0.9-0.7,1.5-1.7,1.6-2.8c0.1-1.1-0.2-2.2-0.8-3.1c-1.4-1.9-4.1-2.2-6-0.8
    C47.8,24,47.2,25,47,26.1c-0.1,1.1,0.2,2.2,0.8,3.1C48.7,30.4,50,30.9,51.3,30.9z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M54.1,37.3c0.7,0.9,1.7,1.5,2.8,1.6c0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6,0c0.9,0,1.8-0.3,2.6-0.9c0.9-0.7,1.5-1.7,1.6-2.8
    c0.1-1.1-0.2-2.2-0.8-3.1l0,0c-0.7-0.9-1.7-1.5-2.8-1.6c-1.1-0.1-2.2,0.2-3.1,0.8C53,32.8,52.6,35.5,54.1,37.3z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M59.4,42.2c-0.1,1.1,0.2,2.2,0.8,3.1c0.7,0.9,1.7,1.5,2.8,1.6c0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6,0c0.9,0,1.8-0.3,2.6-0.9
    c0.9-0.7,1.5-1.7,1.6-2.8c0.1-1.1-0.2-2.2-0.8-3.1c-0.7-0.9-1.7-1.5-2.8-1.6c-1.1-0.1-2.2,0.2-3.1,0.8
    C60.1,40.1,59.6,41.1,59.4,42.2z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M65.6,50.3c-0.1,1.1,0.2,2.2,0.8,3.1c0.7,0.9,1.7,1.5,2.8,1.6c0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6,0c0.9,0,1.8-0.3,2.6-0.9
    c0.9-0.7,1.5-1.7,1.6-2.8c0.1-1.1-0.2-2.2-0.8-3.1c-1.4-1.9-4.1-2.2-6-0.8C66.3,48.1,65.7,49.1,65.6,50.3z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M79.6,63.5c-1.9,1.4-2.2,4.1-0.8,6c0.7,0.9,1.7,1.5,2.8,1.6c0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6,0c0.9,0,1.8-0.3,2.6-0.9
    c0.9-0.7,1.5-1.7,1.6-2.8c0.1-1.1-0.2-2.2-0.8-3.1C84.1,62.4,81.5,62.1,79.6,63.5z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M93,54.5c2.1-1,3.1-3.5,2.2-5.6v0c-1-2.1-3.5-3.1-5.6-2.2c-2.1,1-3.1,3.5-2.2,5.6c0.7,1.6,2.3,2.5,3.9,2.5
    C91.9,54.9,92.4,54.8,93,54.5z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M74.8,17.8c0.6,0,1.2-0.1,1.7-0.4c1-0.5,1.8-1.3,2.2-2.4c0.4-1.1,0.4-2.2-0.1-3.3c-1-2.1-3.5-3.1-5.6-2.2
    c-1,0.5-1.8,1.3-2.2,2.4c-0.4,1.1-0.4,2.2,0.1,3.3C71.6,16.8,73.2,17.8,74.8,17.8z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M77.2,18.9c-2.1,1-3.1,3.5-2.2,5.6c0.7,1.6,2.3,2.5,3.9,2.5c0.6,0,1.2-0.1,1.7-0.4c2.1-1,3.1-3.5,2.2-5.6
    C81.9,18.9,79.3,17.9,77.2,18.9z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M81.3,28.2c-1,0.5-1.8,1.3-2.2,2.4c-0.4,1.1-0.4,2.2,0.1,3.3c0.7,1.6,2.3,2.5,3.9,2.5c0.6,0,1.2-0.1,1.7-0.4
    c2.1-1,3.1-3.5,2.2-5.6C86,28.2,83.5,27.2,81.3,28.2z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M85.4,37.5c-2.1,1-3.1,3.5-2.2,5.6c0.7,1.6,2.3,2.5,3.9,2.5c0.6,0,1.2-0.1,1.7-0.4c2.1-1,3.1-3.5,2.2-5.6
    C90.1,37.5,87.6,36.5,85.4,37.5z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M99.3,58.2c-0.5-1-1.3-1.8-2.4-2.2c-1.1-0.4-2.2-0.4-3.3,0.1c-1,0.5-1.8,1.3-2.2,2.4c-0.4,1.1-0.4,2.2,0.1,3.3
    c0.5,1,1.3,1.8,2.4,2.2c0.5,0.2,1,0.3,1.5,0.3c0.6,0,1.2-0.1,1.7-0.4c1-0.5,1.8-1.3,2.2-2.4C99.8,60.4,99.8,59.2,99.3,58.2
    C99.3,58.2,99.3,58.2,99.3,58.2z"/>
<circle class="st0" cx="162.8" cy="102.8" r="4.3"/>
<circle class="st0" cx="203.4" cy="102.8" r="4.3"/>
<circle class="st0" cx="193.3" cy="102.8" r="4.3"/>
<path class="st0" d="M183.1,98.6c-2.3,0-4.3,1.9-4.3,4.3s1.9,4.3,4.3,4.3c2.3,0,4.3-1.9,4.3-4.3S185.5,98.6,183.1,98.6z"/>
<circle class="st0" cx="173" cy="102.8" r="4.3"/>
<circle class="st0" cx="152.7" cy="102.8" r="4.3"/>
<path class="st0" d="M160.1,90.2c0.3,0,0.6,0,0.9-0.1c1.1-0.2,2.1-0.9,2.7-1.9c0.6-1,0.8-2.1,0.6-3.2v0c-0.5-2.3-2.8-3.7-5.1-3.2
    c-1.1,0.2-2.1,0.9-2.7,1.9c-0.6,1-0.8,2.1-0.6,3.2C156.4,88.9,158.1,90.2,160.1,90.2z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M199.7,81.3c0.3,0,0.6,0,0.9-0.1c2.3-0.5,3.7-2.8,3.2-5.1c-0.5-2.3-2.8-3.7-5.1-3.2c-2.3,0.5-3.7,2.8-3.2,5.1
    C196,80,197.7,81.3,199.7,81.3z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M188.8,75.1c-1.1,0.2-2.1,0.9-2.7,1.9c-0.6,1-0.8,2.1-0.6,3.2c0.4,2,2.2,3.3,4.2,3.3c0.3,0,0.6,0,0.9-0.1
    c2.3-0.5,3.7-2.8,3.2-5.1c-0.2-1.1-0.9-2.1-1.9-2.7C191.1,75.1,189.9,74.9,188.8,75.1z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M178.9,77.4c-2.3,0.5-3.7,2.8-3.2,5.1c0.4,2,2.2,3.3,4.2,3.3c0.3,0,0.6,0,0.9-0.1c1.1-0.2,2.1-0.9,2.7-1.9
    c0.6-1,0.8-2.1,0.6-3.2C183.5,78.3,181.2,76.8,178.9,77.4z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M172.2,80.1c-1-0.6-2.1-0.8-3.2-0.6c-1.1,0.2-2.1,0.9-2.7,1.9s-0.8,2.1-0.6,3.2c0.4,2,2.2,3.3,4.2,3.3
    c0.3,0,0.6,0,0.9-0.1c2.3-0.5,3.7-2.8,3.2-5.1C173.9,81.7,173.2,80.8,172.2,80.1z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M151.1,92.4c2.3-0.5,3.7-2.8,3.2-5.1s-2.8-3.7-5.1-3.2c-2.3,0.5-3.7,2.8-3.2,5.1c0.2,1.1,0.9,2.1,1.9,2.7
    c0.7,0.4,1.5,0.7,2.3,0.7C150.5,92.5,150.8,92.4,151.1,92.4z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M156,68.6c-0.6-1-1.6-1.6-2.7-1.9c-1.1-0.2-2.3,0-3.2,0.6c-1,0.6-1.6,1.6-1.9,2.7c-0.2,1.1,0,2.2,0.6,3.2
    c0.6,1,1.6,1.6,2.7,1.9c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.1,0.9,0.1c0.8,0,1.6-0.2,2.3-0.7C156.6,73.2,157.2,70.6,156,68.6z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M186.6,53.3c0.8,0,1.6-0.2,2.3-0.7c2-1.3,2.6-3.9,1.3-5.9c-1.3-2-3.9-2.6-5.9-1.3c-2,1.3-2.6,3.9-1.3,5.9
    C183.8,52.6,185.2,53.3,186.6,53.3z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M177.1,58.6c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.1,0.9,0.1c0.8,0,1.6-0.2,2.3-0.7c2-1.3,2.6-3.9,1.3-5.9c-1.3-2-3.9-2.6-5.9-1.3
    c-1,0.6-1.6,1.6-1.9,2.7c-0.2,1.1,0,2.2,0.6,3.2C175.1,57.7,176,58.4,177.1,58.6z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M165.3,59c-0.2,1.1,0,2.2,0.6,3.2c0.6,1,1.6,1.6,2.7,1.9c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.1,0.9,0.1c0.8,0,1.6-0.2,2.3-0.7
    c2-1.3,2.6-3.9,1.3-5.9c-0.6-1-1.6-1.6-2.7-1.9c-1.1-0.2-2.2,0-3.2,0.6C166.2,57,165.6,57.9,165.3,59z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M164.5,63.1L164.5,63.1c-1.3-2-3.9-2.6-5.9-1.3c-2,1.3-2.6,3.9-1.3,5.9c0.6,1,1.6,1.6,2.7,1.9
    c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.1,0.9,0.1c0.8,0,1.6-0.2,2.3-0.7C165.2,67.7,165.8,65.1,164.5,63.1z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M148,77.2c0.2-1.1,0-2.2-0.6-3.2c-1.3-2-3.9-2.6-5.9-1.3c-1,0.6-1.6,1.6-1.9,2.7c-0.2,1.1,0,2.2,0.6,3.2
    c0.6,1,1.6,1.6,2.7,1.9c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.1,0.9,0.1c0.8,0,1.6-0.2,2.3-0.7C147.1,79.3,147.7,78.4,148,77.2z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M142.5,60.6c1.4-1.9,1.1-4.5-0.8-6c-0.9-0.7-2-1-3.1-0.8c-1.1,0.1-2.1,0.7-2.8,1.6c-0.7,0.9-1,2-0.8,3.1
    c0.1,1.1,0.7,2.1,1.6,2.8c0.8,0.6,1.7,0.9,2.6,0.9C140.4,62.3,141.7,61.7,142.5,60.6z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M161.3,29.2c0.8,0.6,1.7,0.9,2.6,0.9c0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6,0c1.1-0.1,2.1-0.7,2.8-1.6c1.4-1.9,1.1-4.5-0.8-6v0
    c-0.9-0.7-2-1-3.1-0.8c-1.1,0.1-2.1,0.7-2.8,1.6c-0.7,0.9-1,2-0.8,3.1S160.4,28.5,161.3,29.2z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M155.1,37.3c0.8,0.6,1.7,0.9,2.6,0.9c0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6,0c1.1-0.1,2.1-0.7,2.8-1.6c0.7-0.9,1-2,0.8-3.1
    c-0.1-1.1-0.7-2.1-1.6-2.8c-1.9-1.4-4.5-1.1-6,0.8C152.9,33.2,153.3,35.9,155.1,37.3z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M148.9,45.3c0.8,0.6,1.7,0.9,2.6,0.9c0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6,0c1.1-0.1,2.1-0.7,2.8-1.6c0.7-0.9,1-2,0.8-3.1
    c-0.1-1.1-0.7-2.1-1.6-2.8l0,0c-1.9-1.4-4.5-1.1-6,0.8C146.7,41.2,147.1,43.9,148.9,45.3z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M142,47.4c-0.7,0.9-1,2-0.8,3.1c0.1,1.1,0.7,2.1,1.6,2.8c0.8,0.6,1.7,0.9,2.6,0.9c1.3,0,2.5-0.6,3.4-1.7
    c1.4-1.9,1.1-4.5-0.8-6c-0.9-0.7-2-1-3.1-0.8C143.7,45.9,142.7,46.5,142,47.4z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M135.5,62.7c-1.9-1.4-4.5-1.1-6,0.8c-0.7,0.9-1,2-0.8,3.1s0.7,2.1,1.6,2.8c0.8,0.6,1.7,0.9,2.6,0.9
    c0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6,0c1.1-0.1,2.1-0.7,2.8-1.6C137.8,66.8,137.4,64.1,135.5,62.7z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M125.6,45.9L125.6,45.9c-2.2-1-4.7,0-5.6,2.2c-1,2.1,0,4.7,2.2,5.6c0.6,0.2,1.1,0.4,1.7,0.4
    c0.5,0,1-0.1,1.5-0.3c1.1-0.4,1.9-1.2,2.4-2.2s0.5-2.2,0.1-3.3C127.4,47.2,126.6,46.4,125.6,45.9z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M138.6,16.6c0.6,0.2,1.1,0.4,1.7,0.4c0.5,0,1-0.1,1.5-0.3c1.1-0.4,1.9-1.2,2.4-2.2c0.5-1,0.5-2.2,0.1-3.3
    c-0.4-1.1-1.2-1.9-2.2-2.4c0,0,0,0,0,0c-1-0.5-2.2-0.5-3.3-0.1c-1.1,0.4-1.9,1.2-2.4,2.2C135.5,13.1,136.5,15.6,138.6,16.6z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M134.5,25.9c0.6,0.2,1.1,0.4,1.7,0.4c0.5,0,1-0.1,1.5-0.3c1.1-0.4,1.9-1.2,2.4-2.2c0.5-1,0.5-2.2,0.1-3.3
    s-1.2-1.9-2.2-2.4c-2.1-1-4.7,0-5.6,2.2C131.4,22.4,132.4,24.9,134.5,25.9z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M130.4,35.1c0.6,0.2,1.1,0.4,1.7,0.4c0.5,0,1-0.1,1.5-0.3c1.1-0.4,1.9-1.2,2.4-2.2c0.5-1,0.5-2.2,0.1-3.3
    s-1.2-1.9-2.2-2.4c0,0,0,0,0,0c-2.1-1-4.7,0-5.6,2.2C127.3,31.7,128.2,34.2,130.4,35.1z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M126.3,44.4c0.6,0.2,1.1,0.4,1.7,0.4c0.5,0,1-0.1,1.5-0.3c1.1-0.4,1.9-1.2,2.4-2.2c0.5-1,0.5-2.2,0.1-3.3
    s-1.2-1.9-2.2-2.4c-2.1-0.9-4.7,0-5.6,2.2C123.1,40.9,124.1,43.5,126.3,44.4z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M121.5,55.2c-2.1-0.9-4.7,0-5.6,2.2c-0.5,1-0.5,2.2-0.1,3.3c0.4,1.1,1.2,1.9,2.2,2.4c0.6,0.2,1.1,0.4,1.7,0.4
    c0.5,0,1-0.1,1.5-0.3c1.1-0.4,1.9-1.2,2.4-2.2c0.5-1,0.5-2.2,0.1-3.3C123.3,56.5,122.5,55.7,121.5,55.2z"/>
<path class="st1" d="M42.8,186.6c0,0,0.3-59.3,58.3-60.7c58-1.3,61.2,61,61.2,61"/>
</svg>
```

the following is the **package.json** of my app:

```
{
  "name": "ddddd",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/core": "~4.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/http": "^4.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.16.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "^4.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.12.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "~2.1.3",
    "cc.fovea.cordova.openwith": "1.3.0",
    "cordova": "^9.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^5.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "^3.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-res": "^0.8.1",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^5.0.0",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "firebase-tools": "^6.1.1",
    "http-server": "^0.12.3",
    "ionic": "^5.4.16",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "node": "^10.18.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  },
  "config": {
    "ionic_uglifyjs": "./config/uglifyjs.config.js"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {},
      "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser",
      "ios",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 5.4.16
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.3

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, browser 6.0.0, ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, (and 11 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res (update available: 0.15.4) : 0.8.1
   native-run                             : not installed

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.11.4
   ios-sim    : 8.0.2
   NodeJS     : v12.22.12 (/Users/ffff/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.14.16
   OS         : macOS Monterey
   Xcode      : Xcode 14.0.1 Build version 14A400
```

---

**----- IONIC CODE -----**

```
<ion-grid style="visibility: hidden;" id="tabella1" class="paddingGrid" *ngIf="!this.menuBig">
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col *ngFor="let m of restApi.vociMenu" (click)="openMenu(m)" class="" col-6>
      <ion-card class="cardMenu"  navParams="">
        <p style="text-align:center;">
          <img class="center" style="width:25%; height: 40px;;background: transparent " src="{{getPathImgForSmartphone(m)}}" onerror="this.src='./assets/icon/documenti.svg'"/>
        </p>
        <p style="padding-top: 8%;">{{m.name.toUpperCase() | decodeSpecialChar}}</p>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

*getPathImgForSmartphone(m)* -> return stringh path like "'./assets/icon/myicon.svg"

---

**----- UPDATE 1 -----**

1. When executed as web application or runned **in the XCode simulator the problem does not appear**. It is only shown in the iOS device.
2. Same **web app executed inside Safari in iOS 16 device shows well the SVG images**. So I think the problem is related to the particular format of SVG inside Ionic/Cordova app.
3. I've used a **very simple SVG image that didn't have problem** in iOS 16 native app. So something in the SVG format breaks Ionic/Cordova view. The image follows:

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 200 200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:1.5;">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" style="fill:#fff;"/>
    <path d="M14,100L186,100" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-width:7.5px;"/>
    <path d="M100,14L100,186" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-width:7.5px;"/>
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="70" style="fill:#fff;stroke:#000;stroke-width:7.5px;"/>
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="5" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-width:7.5px;"/>
</svg>
```

4. when executed in XCode (on the device) I see this error (but I think isn't related): ***BUG IN CLIENT OF UIKIT: Setting UIDevice.orientation is not supported. Please use UIWindowScene.requestGeometryUpdate***

Any idea? Thx for any suggestion.

**----- UPDATE 2 -----**

it seemed to me that the cubic Bézier curve caused the bug, but it's not true. The bug reflects on rendering the SVG but it's not determined by the nature of the SVG.

**Instead I think it's a problem of the `<ion-card>` or `<ion-grid>` refresh.** I tried to change some background to understand better and sometime the refresh problem is evident.

Look at this animated gif. I think it's a bug of Ionic/Cordova with something introduced in iOS 16. Back to the origin :(

[image]

**----- TRIVIAL SOLUTION -----**

I tried to use the ionic icons with the ion-icon directive and the problem is there again. So, I finally converted all the SVGs in PNG images and adapted the UI.

SVGs have huge problem after iOS 16, especially it seems to me with Ionic. My SVGs have problems because they were exported in SVGs from Adobe and I think that Apple from iOS 16 is more strict on SVG format/language. This is my hypothesis.

Comment: Have you tried viewing the problematic images directly in mobile Safari / iOS 16? I'm wondering if there's an underlying wkwebview issue.

Comment: Yes, same app viewed in Safari has no problem with SVG! So the problem is not Safari or wkwebview, but something when it's executed as native app. Maybe something in Ionic cordova InAppBrowser interacting with SVG?

Comment: Is that app available on the store ? I'd like to try and inspect

Comment: Nope, sorry. It's an enterprise App. But I can give you details. thx a lot

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I solved it by adding css property "will-change: transform;" on the affected elements.
I don't know why, but I think the resolution is due to enabling hardware acceleration (or GPU acceleration) caused by "will-change: transform;"

Comment: the problem I had is strictly correlated to how the SVG was made but I did not find what is the cause...I'll try your workaround ASAP and thx.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, based on Assemblea icon, the part rendered in the svg file are "circle" tags, the part not rendered are "path" tags.

Probably is something related to "c" command?

Comment: thx Giuseppe, yes I think this is the right "path" for the bug. The problem is something in the "path" directive that raise problem in Ionic/Cordova render. What is strange is that the same Icons are rendered well in Safari!

Comment: Try to create a very simple icon with just 2 paths: one with "c" command (lower case - relative coords) and another with "C" command (upper case - absolute coords).

BTW, this seems strange to me:

c-2-1.3-4.6-0.7-5.9,1.3
it should be:

c -2,-1.3 -4.6,-0.7 -5.9,1.3

Probably the command format was messed out by the minus sign in the conversion process?

Comment: Sorry Giuseppe, it's not the SVG the problem. This was a false flag but thx a lot for your contribution